# Saving numpy array to json

Tags: python, arrays, json, numpy

Im trying to save a numpy array to a json but since a ndarray is not JSON serializable I am converting them to lists. My problem is that this consumes an excesive amount of RAM. Is there any other lightweight method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [numpyencoder](https://pypi.org/project/numpyencoder/):

```
import numpy as np
import json
from numpyencoder import NumpyEncoder

numpy_data = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])

print(json.dumps(numpy_data, cls=NumpyEncoder))
```

Comment: Shows great improvement!